# Trouble inserting ip addresses converted to bigint to temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

The ideal situation here is that using the scalar based function, grab a list of IP addresses, stored as varchar's, convert to integers, and match another table of geographical information.

Problem is, ***I believe the column containing the IP's is having trouble***. I cannot see through a select if there is junk or special characters, only ip's stored fine.

Wondering if my syntax is missing something, there are better checks beyond checking for NULL, empty fields, all of which I have tried. Even an ISNUMERIC(convert function(ip's))
I can convert to integer if I select one record from the history table containing a good IP. So there is something going on I can't see.

**Any advice on putting in further failsafes, to ignore any "bad data?"**

Below is one such MSSQL query.

```
WITH CTE
AS (
  --get distinct list of ips from tblHistory
  SELECT DISTINCT ip
  FROM tblHistory aaa WITH (NOLOCK)
  --Join history to report table on an id
  INNER JOIN tblReport bbb WITH (NOLOCK) ON aaa.tbl_id = bbb.tbl_id
    AND aaa.inserteddate > dateadd(d, - 5, getdate())
    AND ip <> ''
  )
--convert distinct list and insert into temp table (bad design... but it's way faster for some reason)
--using scalar function to insert ip's converted to bigint to temp table, to match against OtherTable
SELECT dbo.IPAddressToNumber(cte.ip) ipint
  ,ip
INTO #temp
FROM cte

--now join against the temp table and update where the ip int matches
UPDATE aaaa
SET text_column = '[Text Comment To Add] ' + comments
  ,updatecolumnvalueto_one = 1
FROM tblHistory aaaa
INNER JOIN tblReport bbbb ON aaaa.tbl_id = bbbb.tbl_id
INNER JOIN #temp ON #temp.ip = bbbb.ip
INNER JOIN OtherTable c ON #temp.ipint BETWEEN c.beginnumber
    AND c.endnumber
WHERE inserteddate > dateadd(d, - 5, getdate())
```

Comment: you may consider regex to validate your data

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this later, I wound up using where isnumeric, after each FROM cte. 
where isnumeric(replace(ip, '.', '')) = 1
(DB contained some junk rows in the IP, brackets and such)